# HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured! in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, sessionfactory

I have the following configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = DemoApplication.class)
public class JpaConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

    @Value("${dataSource.driverClassName}")
    private String driver;
    @Value("${dataSource.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${dataSource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${dataSource.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;
    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String hbm2ddlAuto;

    @Bean
    public DataSource configureDataSource() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName(driver);
        config.setJdbcUrl(url);
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);

        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean configureEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(configureDataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.dataart.cashmashine");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, dialect);
        jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, hbm2ddlAuto);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(HibernateEntityManagerFactory hemf) {
        return hemf.getSessionFactory();
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
dataSource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
dataSource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cash_mashine
dataSource.username=marc
dataSource.password=marc
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
```

In dao I write following rows:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
@Override
public CreditCard findCard(String cardNumber) {
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

when executes

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
```

I see following error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext
>   configured!

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

```
spring:
    jpa:
        properties:
            hibernate:
                current_session_context_class: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

above config in application.yml can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @Transactional at a public service method which is invoking the DAO.